# display links in php

Tags: php, email, hyperlink

I know this is simple but my brain is fried from trying to solve a different problem!

I'm using php's mail function to email the user. Below is my code. See the a href link, how do I get this to display as an actual link within the php?

```
$email=someone@example.com;
$content= "Dear Whoever,    
NB: Please click <a href=\"document.pdf\" target=\"_blank\">here</a> to read and download the terms and conditions.";

mail( "$email", "Welcome", $content, "From: support@example.com");
```

Comment: `$email=someone@example.com;` => `$email="someone@example.com";`

Comment: `mail( "$email", "Welcome", $content, "From: support@epubdirect.com");` => `mail( $email, "Welcome", $content, "From: support@epubdirect.com");`

Comment: Just to note (to the OP and the general world) - fredley was replying to the question before it was codified, so the `<ahref...>` tag in the `$content` didn't appear. He was (assumedly) then understandable misunderstanding the question.

Comment: Edited the error in the code.

Comment: If his code is wrong post it as an answer, don't edit his question. Now people surfing in are going to be looking for a differently problem because you've fixed it in his question.

Comment: The error in his code has nothing to do with the question of sending HTML. Anyway I'll revert and shift it to my answer instead then.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As noted above, your code has error. It should be:

```
email='someone@example.com';
$content= "Dear Whoever,    
NB: Please click <a href=\"document.pdf\" target=\"_blank\">here</a> to read and download the terms and conditions.";

mail( $email, "Welcome", $content, "From: support@example.com");
```

You would need to set the mime type to HTML in the header, and use it as a parameter in the mail() function.

[From the manual](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mail.php)

```
// To send HTML mail, the Content-type header must be set
$headers  = 'MIME-Version: 1.0' . "\r\n";
$headers .= 'Content-type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1' . "\r\n";

// Additional headers
$headers .= 'To: Mary <mary@example.com>, Kelly <kelly@example.com>' . "\r\n";
$headers .= 'From: Birthday Reminder <birthday@example.com>' . "\r\n";
$headers .= 'Cc: birthdayarchive@example.com' . "\r\n";
$headers .= 'Bcc: birthdaycheck@example.com' . "\r\n";

// Mail it
mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers);
```

Though I usually use [SwiftMailer](http://www.swiftmailer.org/) and it has other neat features.

Comment: Sending HTML email without a plain text alternative is a good way to ramp up your spam score. Always use multipart MIME email if you want to include an HTML version.